# Electrical net discovery (visualization)

Tags: algorithm, graph, visualization

I'm searching for a method to discover an interconnections in electrical network, from sources (multiple) to ground. I have some sources, then layer of switches and receivers at the end. My job is to discover which receiver consume power from which source. I think that solution is graph theory but I can't find straight solution. Any suggestions? I have in my mind some terms: flow network, graph colouring, path colouring, but how can I use them  together?

Comment: Once you reach a receiver, how do you decide from which source it's consuming?

Comment: Generally there is only one path between source and receiver, configurable by a series of switches. Configuration can change over time. My job is to discover current configuration. This is what I'm saying about [link](http://www.elkomtech.com.pl/popup.php?plik=img/e6271781_large.jpg)

Comment: Then if you start depth first search from each of the source and keep coloring/marking the child you visit. each path should finish with a receiver and if you carry the source's name with you, you make a unique (source , receiver) pair. Error out if you find any leaf child(i.e. receiver) already visited. I think pseudo code for DFS is readily available

Comment: [LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) Thx for answer